# nunjucks, как прокинуть дочерний компонент в шаблон?

Tags: hbs

Кто-нибудь использует nunjucks в качестве шаблонизатора? Не пойму как пробросить дочерний компонент в шаблон, по примеру с hbs {{{ component ChatItem.component}}}